# Исправьте небольшой фрагмент кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сначала программа спрашивает у пользователя, какое у него настроение. Затем ответ анализируется. Предполагается, что пользователь отвечает словом или фразой, записанной строчными буквами.

Если в ответе пользователя есть ключевые слова вроде «хорошее», «прекрасно» (в любой форме), программа отвечает что-нибудь подходящее — например «Отлично, у меня тоже всё хорошо ».
Если же встречаются слова вроде «плохо», то нужно ответить что-то подходящее и на этот случай (например, «Ничего, скоро всё наладится»).

Если ключевых слов того или другого типа не найдено, программа отвечает что-то нейтральное или извиняется и говорит, что не понимает пользователя. То же происходит, если в ответе есть «не» или вопросительный знак.

Случай, когда в ответе есть и «хорошие», и «плохие» слова, можно не рассматривать.

```
print('Как у вас настроение?')
a = input()
if a.startswith('хорош') or a.startswith('прекрасн'):
    print('Отлично, у меня тоже всё хорошо :)')
elif 'плох' in a:
    print('Ничего, скоро всё наладится')
elif 'не' in a:
    print('Извините, но я вас не понимаю')
elif '?' in a:
    print('Извините, но я вас не понимаю')
else:
    print('Извините, но я вас не понимаю')
```

**такое замечание от учителя:**
не нужен здесь метод startwith. Это же может быть середина предложения. Просто первая проверка должна быть на то, что сразу нужно "отсечь".

Comment: 1) Привести `a` в нижний регистр 2) вместо `a` использовать что-то более понятное, например, `text` 3) вместо `startswith` использовать оператор `in` 4) судя по коду условия `elif 'не' in a:` и `elif '?' in a:` не нужны -- достаточно `else:`

Comment: @gil9red тогда если ввести ответ "нехорошее", то программа напишет: "отлично, у меня тоже все хорошо". А должна написать 'Не понимаю вас'

Comment: А почему не вывести `Ничего, скоро всё наладится`? :) По хорошему, вам нужно сделать токенизацию -- чтобы получить список слов из текста, после с этим работать. Но если у вас можно только одним словом отвечать, то можно без токенизации, но вводить кучу ограничений, типа `нехорошо`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print('Как у вас настроение?')
text = input().lower()
if "не" in text:
    print('Извините, но я вас не понимаю')
elif 'хорош' in text or 'прекрасн' in text:
    print('Отлично, у меня тоже всё хорошо :)')
elif 'плох' in text:
    print('Ничего, скоро всё наладится')
else:
    print('Извините, но я вас не понимаю')
```

Comment: Если ввести ответ "нехорошее", то программа напишет: "отлично, у меня тоже все хорошо". А должна написать 'Не понимаю вас'